# Paperjs split line segments

Tags: javascript, canvas, 2d, vector-graphics, paperjs

I am using paperjs and now have a need to do vector segmentation of freely drawn line segments. Specifically, it has a function similar to erasing, and the eraser itself has a volume. Then the intersecting parts of the eraser need to be removed and a new vector path generated。
I use the subtract and intersection methods from paperjs, but there are still many problems. I am not sure whether it is because I am not familiar with them or because paperjs is flawed.
Or how to get some algorithm to solve this problem.

At the first, it will be
[image: first]

at the finally,it should be
[image: final]

i move the eraser in middle,and it should divide to 4 parts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.